# Jenkins Pipeline Custom Scripts (shutdown application)

Tags: jenkins

I have several jenkins pipelines that in my case call "docker-compose up" at the end of the build to run the containers/application. Now, I don't need the containers/application to be up all the time and I would like to have a way from the jenkins pipeline page to shutdown (docker-compose stop) the application to free resources for other builds. Do you know any good way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Like when you want to stop the containers? How are you doing `docker compose up` from the pipeline?

Comment: I would like to stop the containers whenever requested, the best think would be a menu entry "Shutdown" or something like "Custom scripts -> Shutdown". About the "docker-compose up" is called in the deploy stage of the build.

Comment: So, do you have a declarative pipeline job?

Comment: In the pipeline configuration - pipeline definition - there is the script (not a jenkinsfile) with `stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh '''...something else...
                    docker-compose up -d
                '''
            }
        }`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a pipeline job script stage to stop the containers using a choice parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I have done it looking at
[Converting Conditional Build Steps to Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/).

```
pipeline {
agent any

parameters {
    choice(
        choices: 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container\nrun_docker_containers\nstop_docker_containers',
        description: '',
        name: 'REQUESTED_ACTION')
}

tools {
    maven 'Maven x.x.x'
    jdk 'jdkYuWZ'
}

environment {
    SVN_URL = 'http://svn.myexample.com/svn/myproject/trunk/'
    DOCKER_PROJECT_DIR = '/home/myuser/docker/containers/myproject/trunk'
}
stages {
    stage ('Initialize') {
        steps {
            sh '''
                echo "Initialize..."
            '''
        }
    }

    stage ('Checkout') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container' }
        }
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: ' something here ', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: "$SVN_URL"]], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
        }
    }

    stage ('Build') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'mvn clean package' 
        }
    }

    stage ('Test') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'echo "Other tests..."' 
        }
    }

    stage ('Deploy') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'echo "The deploy here"'
        }
    }

    stage ('Docker compose run') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'full_deploy_and_run_docker_container' || 
                params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'run_docker_containers'
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh '''
                cd $DOCKER_PROJECT_DIR
                docker-compose up -d
            '''
        }
    }

    stage ('Docker compose stop') {
        when {
            expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION == 'stop_docker_containers' }
        }
        steps {
            sh '''
                cd $DOCKER_PROJECT_DIR
                docker-compose stop
            '''
        }
    }

    stage ('Cleanup') {
        steps {
            cleanWs()
       }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `choice parameter (ex: stop_containers)` with values `YES` and `NO` in your Jenkins job that is responsible for stopping the containers.

Then in the `Build` section select `Execute shell` and add the following script to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$stop_containers" = "YES" ]
then
    //Command for stopping containers....

else
    echo "Do Nothing."
fi
```

Now, whenever you will run your job it will ask if you want to stop the containers or not. Choose the required option, `YES` if you want to stop the containers.

If it is a `Pipeline Job` then you can define a stage to perform the stopping the container operation.

```
stage('stop containers') {
    properties(
    [parameters([choice(choices: ["YES", "NO"].join("\n"),
    description: 'Some choice parameter', 
    name: 'STOP_CONTAINERS')])])
    agent label:'some-node'
    when {
    expression {
        return env.STOP_CONTAINERS = 'YES';
        }
    }
    steps {
        //command to stop containers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way, you can use sh command in jenkins pipeline for this.

```
node {

    stage('stop') {

        sh "ssh root@host.com"
        sh "cd /diretorio_do_docker-compose/"
        sh "docker-compose stop"

    }
}
```